# Some products not saving their cost price

Tags: price

On certain products on my Magento store it won't save the cost prices. It always re sets them to zero.

Has anyone else had this issue?
I can't see any difference between the products it is happening on. It seems to be on mainly older ones but not only as some of the older ones are working just fine. I am also not able to export the cost price when this issue happens.

Thanks.